# Getting error while connection to postgres DB

Tags: c#, postgresql

While opening a connection, I get following error:

> The Connection is not open., Trace:    at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.CheckConnectionState()\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Below is the code used:

```
public void Connect()
{
    if (mConnection == null)
    {
        ExceptionHandler(RdbError.InternalError, new Exception("Connection found (NULL) in pool, trying to recreate"));
    }

    try
    {

        if (mConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            mConnection.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        ExceptionHandler(RdbError.InternalError, new Exception("Connection could not be opened normally, state was: " + (int)mConnection.State + ", full state:  " + (int)mConnection.FullState));

    }
}
```

In Trace I get the state and full state as 0. How to handle such exception and what state it is returning?
The connection string used is :
Server=127.0.0.1;port=5432;Database=abc;User Id=postgres;Password=****

The version of `Npgsql.dll` used is `2.1.3.0`

Sometimes it gets successfully connected and in long run I get the above error.

Comment: Did you miss database name in the connection string?

Comment: No,the connection string is correct. Actually sometimes the connection is established with multiple clients and sometimes I get this error. Please help..